# Can we avoid all algebraic numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-approximation

We say a polynomial $p$ in $n$ variables degree at most four, and coefficients $-1,0,1$ is $n$-plain.

We say $x$ is an $n$-plain algebraic number if there exists an $n$-plain polynomial $p$ such that
$$x = \min_{t\in \mathbb{R}} t $$
such that $$\exists y \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}: p(t,y) = 0.$$

We say $\alpha$ *avoids* all algebraic numbers if
for any $n$-plain algebraic number $x$, we have that
$$ |x-\alpha| \geq 2^{-n^{100}} ,$$
for all $n>100$.
(Note that every algebraic number is an $n$-plain algebraic number for some $n$.)

If you like you can replace 100 by any other convenient constant.

---

As there are not that many $n$ plain polynomials, there cannot be too many $n$-plain algebraic numbers. And as the forbidden intervals around them are very small, we know that there must be some numbers that avoid all algebraic numbers.
Can we find one that is polynomial time computable?
Is the Euler number e avoiding all algebraic numbers?

Comment: I guess you meant to say "$\alpha$ avoids all $n$-plain algebraic numbers"?

Comment: Is there some restriction on (the vector) $y$? For example, if the entries of $y$ are allowed to be complex, then $t$ will be $0$ for all $n$-plain polynomials.

Comment: - As every algebraic number is $n$-plain algebraic, I really mean to avoid all algebraic numbers. 
- The vector $y$ should be real, otherwise, no restrictions.